# jQuery replacing only one character

Tags: javascript

jQuery:

```
console.log("'Wild.jpg'".replace("'", ""));
```

Output:

```
Wild.jpg'
```

How can I resolve this and make the output as Wild.jpg?

Comment: use this console.log("'Wild.jpg'".replace(/'/g, ""));

Comment: This isn't a jQuery problem, it's javascript and you should use a regex with the /g parameter to do a global replace.

Comment: a regex would do this more efficiently rather than going for the jquery

Comment: I just removed the jQuery tag from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use RegEx with the `g` modifier instead of an ordinary string replacement:

```js
console.log("'Wild.jpg'".replace(/'/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. here we gave /g to replace all.

```js
console.log("'Wild.jpg'".replace(/'/g, ""));
```